# I cannot run a release build of a C# application on other computers

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a client-server application built in c# over .net 4.5 framework. I cannot run the server side on other computers. I tried different computers with .net up to date.  The weird thing is that the client side works without any problem. Can someone help me?

Informações da Excepção: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
   em System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   em System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   em System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare)
   em System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(System.Uri, System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption, System.Guid ByRef, Boolean ByRef, System.IO.Stream ByRef, System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream ByRef, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle ByRef)
   em System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(System.Uri, System.Uri, System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption, System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy, Boolean)
   em System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()
   em System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit()
   em System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage..ctor(System.Uri, System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy)
   em Server2UI.MainWindow..ctor()

Informações da Excepção: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Comment: What happens when you try to run it? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Do not make us guess what is transpiring on your PC, we are not mind readers and (*most of us*) do not work for the NSA. Always provide the expected result and the actual result. In the case of an Exception provide all the details (type, message, stacktrack, and again for any inner exceptions recursively). See [ask] a good question and always try to include an [mcve].

Comment: @AlexTelon I got the error message "Application has stopped working" in one computer, but I did not get any error on the other computers I tested -
 Instead, nothing happens.

Comment: Search the **windows event log** to find why the app stopped working. If that does not clear it up for you then post your findings in your question.

Comment: @Igor I have a small app with a simple UI created with wpf. When I try to open the app, nothing happens and I get no error messages. Everything is up to date on the target machines. I don't think there's much more I can tell you.

Comment: Search the [Windows Event Log](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997769(v=exchg.65).aspx). Unhandled application crash information will be written here by the OS. If you can't tell us anything more how do you expect us to help you? You provided no useful information and no code. If you want to fix this **you** will have to do some troubleshooting / investigation.

Comment: You need to log information when the application working. Did you do that? You can debug your code on your dev PC, how it is often difficult to debug in a production environment. There are dozens of reasons an application cannot run. Runtime library issues, networking issue..ect

Comment: @Igor I get an unheld "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException" and a KERNELBASE.dll application error. See above

Comment: Look at names of the exception types and the stack trace starting at the bottom. Looks to me (*and keep in mind I do not know anything about your source code*) that there is an image that is being loaded from disk found on the wpf form that is not included in your application's directory (or there abouts).

Comment: @Igor I noticed it and that was exactly the problem. I was loading the image from a specific folder on the dev machine. I didn't know about the windows event log. Really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @DiogoCosta - Glad to help and glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at names of the exception types and the stack trace starting at the bottom. Looks to me (*and keep in mind I do not know anything about your source code*) that there is an image that is being loaded from disk found on the WPF form that is not included in your application's directory (*or there abouts*).